# creating 3d house and walk through in it on web

Tags: hosting, vrml, sandy3d

I'm trying to build a house and hosting it on web. It should be possible for the user to walk through around the house. Does sandy 3D and flash could support this application or have to go for VRML

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Sandy and Flash for 3D, but i can tell you that VRML isn't an option. I'm afraid you will struggle to find any modern-day browsers and/or browser plugins which will allow you to display VRML models.

EDIT:

Update: Maybe you could try http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/Java3D